# Are SMS within the European Union considered international?

Tags: javascript, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I have an app that needs to reach customers all over the world. It's unfeasible for me to purchase phone numbers in every country so my hope was to purchase a number in each geographic region with the hopes that the costs of each SMS to and from these numbers and to the countries surrounding this location would be cheaper.

As an example I purchased a number in France with the hope that SMS between France and the rest of the EU would not be treated as international SMS. Does anyone know if this is true? Is there a specific country to use that would be advantageous for all international SMS in cases where a customer resides where I don't have a phone number?

Even better would be an API service that would help me determine which phone number should be used based on the customers location. For example if the customer resides in Estonia, call the API service to determine which phone number out of my list of numbers I should use for optimal pricing.

My app is written in javascript and utilizes their standard API, but I have heard there is some sort of pricing API that could potentially be useful in this situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because telco billing policies aren't programming related.

Comment: To answer you title question, it is considered international

Comment: So asking about an API for determining billing costs within the framework of the telecom industry isn't programming related? Gotcha. /s

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have built your app using Twilio, as your tag suggests, the costs to send an SMS to a country are local to that country, as seen on the pricing page for each country ([see the pricing for Estonia](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/ee), for example). The number from which you send the message doesn't have any bearing on the eventual cost.

We do also have a [pricing API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/pricing/messaging) that you can call to find out how much an outbound message will cost to a particular country.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks @philnash! My question is more around the cost to reply to my SMS. The use case here is that customers receiving these SMS's will be responding to my SMS, and are often on pay as you go or el-cheapo plans. My greatest concern is what _their_ cost will be; I want to minimize that as much as possible by using local or nearby numbers, but this gets expensive fast. I assume the pricing API isn't able to determine those costs?

Comment: Ah, no, you're right. Each user will have their own contracts with their own pricing. Sending a message from Estonia to your French number, for example, will be an international message for them and you can't know what that cost will be. Best bet for your users is to have as many local numbers as you can.

Comment: @BrettMcLain: Hi, I'm also tackling the same issue with a similar concern. Did you ever come up with a solution to minimize the customers' reply costs?

Comment: @EliRose The solution is to get local numbers for as many of the countries you operate in as possible.